# Android app crashes after SDK-tools update (NoClassDefFound, google analytics)

Tags: android, google-analytics

I just updated my android SDK tools to the newly released version (tools version 22, platform tools version 17)

But now I'm encountering some problems while building my app.
The app still launches, but it gives me this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
```

It has that exception on this line:

```
EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);
```

Before the SDK tools update, it was working fine,
the libGoogleAnalyticsV2 jar is in the libs folder, in the build path, as it should be.

Git shows me that, while building, eclipse is adding this line in the classpath:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
```

That's the only difference I see

any idea what's causing this?

Comment: At least one other person seems to be having JAR-related problems: https://groups.google.com/group/adt-dev/msg/e72062af02e4b98f Personally, I'm not touching R22 for a bit, so I do not know what you may be experiencing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution

In the project properties (eclipse) -> java build path -> order and export
make sure that all your jars in the libs folder are checked.

Comment: UPDATE: I had another library that wasn't working, make sure that android private libraries is also checked